# Setting Environment Variables GTS_CFLAGS and GTS_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config

Tags: command-line, apt, bash, sudo, environment-variables

I tried doing a ./configure on a file and received the following response:

'checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for GTS... no
configure: error: Package requirements (gts >= 0.7.4) were not met:

No package 'gts' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables GTS_CFLAGS
and GTS_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
'

I was wondering how I could edit the environment variables so that it could locate the GTS package?

I have tried to 'sudo apt-get ...' but am not in the sudoers file

Thanks :)

Comment: So have you built and installed libgts elsewhere (such as your home directory)? If so, what is the path prefix,exactly?

Comment: I have not installed libgts elsewhere

Comment: Well until you do that, setting environment variables isn't going to help - it's not hard, however it might be easier to ask your system administrator to install the `libgts-dev` package for you